# MEF load types that implement interface and match attributes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mef

Lets say i have an interface IFileLoader and the attribute FileTypeAttribute

And I implement IFileLoader in JPEGLoader with [FileType(".jpg")]

Can i use MEF to load the class (JPEGLoader) that implements IFileLoader and matches .jpg as file extension so I can implement the following method:

```
public void IFileLoader GetLoader(string filename);
```

Can this be done with MEF, or should I stick to this:

```
var allTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
var classes = allTypes.Where(t => t.IsClass && ! t.IsAbstract);
var fileLoaders = classes.where(t => typeof(IFileLoader).IsAssignableFrom(t));
var forType = fileLoaders.Where(t => t.GetAtributeValue<FileTypeAttribute,string>(t => t.FileType, string.Empty) == fileType);
var loaderInstances = fileLoaders.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IFileLoader);
```

Or the above turned into ILookup at least, or maybe something else that I haven't considered?

I'd like to be able to implement the IFileLoader in different assemblies of the project or even in plugin assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the file loader you need by using `MEF`and attachnig `Metadata` to the exported parts.

**Create metadata interface and attribute.**

```
public interface IFileTypeMetadata
{
    string FileExtension { get; }
}
```

The interface can contain as many properties you need. For this particular problem, it contain only one property `FileExtension`. It is important that the property has only `getter`. `MEF` is designed not to allow changing of metadata at runtime. Then create the attribute that holds the metadata:

```
public class FileTypeAttribute : Attribute, IFileTypeMetadata    
{        
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
}
```

The `FileTypeAttribute` class implements `IFileTypeMetadata` interface, and you can add a `setter` to the `FileExtension` property. It is needed for implementing the `FileLoader` classes, and `MEF` will not complain because we will access the metadata via the `IFileTypeMetadata` interface which contain properties that have only `getters`

**Create the interface that file loader classes implement and the file loader classes.**

```
public interface IFileLoader
{
    string LoadFile();
}
```

The interface contains only one method for the sake of simplicity. And here is example of two different dummy file loader classes:

```
[Export(typeof(IFileLoader))]
[FileType(FileExtension = ".jpg")]
public class JpgFileLoader : IFileLoader
{
    public string LoadFile()
    {
        return "JPG"; 
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IFileLoader))]
[FileType(FileExtension = ".png")]
public class PngFileLoader : IFileLoader
{
    public string LoadFile()
    {
        return "PNG";
    }
}
```

Both classes implement the `IFileLoader` interface and are exported as `IFileLoader` parts, but they have different metadata, via the `FileType` attribute.

**Create the composition container**

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("path to directory where dll's are located");
var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
compositionContainer.ComposeParts();
```

**Access exported parts**

```
var fileLoaders = compositionContainer.GetExports<IFileLoader, IFileTypeMetadata>();

var jpgFileLoader = fileLoaders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.FileExtension == ".jpg");

if (jpgFileLoader != null)
    Console.WriteLine(jpgFileLoader.Value.LoadFile()); //should print "JPG"

var pngFileLoader = fileLoaders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.FileExtension == ".png");

if (pngFileLoader != null)
    Console.WriteLine(pngFileLoader.Value.LoadFile()); //should print "PNG"
```